# Cell fracture not working with physics

Tags: animation, physics

So I have a cube that has been cell fractured. And I selected all of them and used the fracture physics tool to have the cube react to a ball hitting it. but when I changed the setting for Enable Deactivation and Start Deactivation so that it won't start until the ball hits it, and press "copy from active" in the toolbar, the fractured cube won't move at all.

Comment: IS the sphere a rigid body object? If it is, and it's still not working, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: well I looked into it further, and it was the rigid body speed settings. it was set to 0. now it works fine.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer then :)

Comment: oh right. He he.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I goofed. It turned out to be the rigid body world settings in the scene tab.
Turns out the speed was at zero, so there wasn't any chance that the fractured cube could move.